# Microsoft /oauth2/v2.0/authorize 'amr_values' request parameter is not supported. (MFA)

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-identity-platform, microsoft-partnercenter-java

I'm trying to authenticate against the Microsoft **https://login.microsoftonline.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize** endpoint with enforcing MFA. Following the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-oapx/0fc398ca-88d0-4118-ae60-c3033e396e60) this is done by adding the **&amr_values=ngcmfa** request parameter to the authorization url. If doing so I get the following error:

> AADSTS901002: The 'amr_values' request parameter is not supported.

When I instead  use the  https://login.microsoftonline.com/oauth2/authorize (without v2.0) it works fine.
The issue is that using this endpoint leads to internal server errors(500) when requesting the partner center api of microsoft. E.g. **https://api.partnercenter.microsoft.com/v1/profiles/organization**

So the question is how to enforce MFA with the v2.0 endpoint?